# Problem in finding the number of all paths from (0,0) to (n,n) visiting each square exactly once

Tags: c++, backtracking

I am trying to learn about backtracking and I have come across the problem outlined in the title. I have used a set `visited` to keep track of all the squares I've visited. I have written the following code, but it doesn't seem to work. I always end up having some squares unvisited. Please help.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int n = 4;
int cnt;

using coords = pair<int, int>;

bool inGrid(coords pos)
{
    return (pos.first < n && pos.first >= 0 && pos.second >= 0 && pos.second < n)?(true):(false);
}

set<coords> possibleSteps(coords pos)
{
    set<coords> sc;
    sc.insert({pos.first, pos.second+1});
    sc.insert({pos.first, pos.second-1});
    sc.insert({pos.first+1, pos.second});
    sc.insert({pos.first-1, pos.second});
    return sc;
}

void search(int steps, coords pos, set<coords> visited)
{
    if (pos == coords {n-1, n-1} && steps == n*n-1) {
        ++cnt;
        return;
    }
    visited.insert(pos);
    auto pSteps = possibleSteps(pos);
    for(auto &s : pSteps) {
        if (inGrid(s) && !visited.count(s))
            search(steps+1, s, visited);
    }

}
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter grid dimension n = ";
    cin >> n;
    set<coords> visited;
    search(0, {0,0}, visited);
    cout << cnt;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JohnFilleau I meant to do it by copy, because I think that in every new call of search a separate one should be kept. But maybe I haven't understood the concept properly.

Comment: What are inputs and expected outputs? BTW: Whenever you see `x ? true : false`, it is the same as `bool(x)`. Similarly, `x ? false : true` is `!bool(x)`. If `x` is already a boolean expression, the explicit conversion can be elided, too.

Comment: How did you determine that you have "some squares unvisited"?

Comment: `cnt` is never initialized. The output of this program can be an arbitrary number and it could change between runs for this reason...

Comment: @fabian • static storage variables (including externally linkable globals) are zero initialized.  (They'll probably be in the zero-initialized BSS segment.)